# FizzBuzz using limited number of conditions and StringBuilder

Tags: java, fizzbuzz

All of you know the trivial `fizzbuzz` question during the first junior interviews. In my case, it was more than write a solution. There were more requirements:

1. Only two `if\else` statements.
2. `StringBuilder` required.
3. No `Map`, `Collection`.
4. No ternary operator.
5. Only Java core (8 or 11).
6. You have only 5 minutes (in my case, but for you it doesn't matter).

My solution with three `if` statements:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i%3==0 && i%5==0) {
        System.out.println("fizzBuzz");
    } else if (i%5==0) {
        System.out.println("Buzz");
    } else if (i%3==0) {
        System.out.println("fizz");
    } else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

But yeah, there are three 'if' and no `StringBuilder`. Okay, let's see two 'if' example:

```
List<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(3, "Fizz");
map.put(5, "Buzz");
for (int num = 1; num <= n; num++) {
    String s = "";
    for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
        if (num % key == 0) {
            s += map.get(key);
        }
    }
    if (s.equals("")) {
        s += Integer.toString(num);
    }
    answer.add(s);
}
```

And again it's wrong: two 'if' but no `StringBuilder`.

Can I ask for a favor? Help me solve this problem.

Comment: `s += map.get(key);` can very well become `s.append(map.get(key))` if `s` is a `StringBuilder` and not a `String`, no?

Comment: That and you can also change the `List<String>` to be a string builder as well.

Comment: But there is Map<>.  Can you do it without a map?

Comment: @junior_java_develop can you use an `else` beside those two `if`s?

Comment: @junior_java_develop also, should Fizz/Buzz/FizzBuzz be printed with the number or in place of the number? I mean, I see your code does the latter, but is that the requirement or your interpretation of the requirements?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it should work like '1 2 fizz 4 buzz fizz 7 8 fizz buzz' and etc.
about cycles: if()x2 else{}x2

Comment: @junior_java_develop I suppose the ternary operator is not allowed either? (anyway, it would be a lot more helpful if, instead of answering one question at a time you could [edit] your question to include the complete and detailed requirements of the problem)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, you are right. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your solution with the map was very close, and nobody said "no arrays" :)

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Object[][] m = {{3, "Fizz"}, {5, "Buzz"}};
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (Object[] o : m) {
                if (i % (int) (o[0]) == 0) {
                    found = true;
                    sb.append((String) (o[1]));
                }
            }

            if (!found) {
                sb.append(i);
            }

            sb.append(" ");
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz 16 17 Fizz 19 Buzz Fizz 22 23 Fizz Buzz 26 Fizz 28 29 FizzBuzz 31 32 Fizz 34 Buzz Fizz 37 38 Fizz Buzz 41 Fizz 43 44 FizzBuzz 46 47 Fizz 49 Buzz Fizz 52 53 Fizz Buzz 56 Fizz 58 59 FizzBuzz 61 62 Fizz 64 Buzz Fizz 67 68 Fizz Buzz 71 Fizz 73 74 FizzBuzz 76 77 Fizz 79 Buzz Fizz 82 83 Fizz Buzz 86 Fizz 88 89 FizzBuzz 91 92 Fizz 94 Buzz Fizz 97 98 Fizz Buzz
```

Having said that, I think 5 minutes is a bit too strict for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a simpler solution than the answer by Federico (in my humble opinion):

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        sb.append("Fizz");
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        sb.append("Buzz");
    }
    String str = sb.toString();
    str = str.replaceAll("^$", String.valueOf(i));
    System.out.print(str + " ");
}
```

What happens here is that Fizz and Buzz are stored into the `StringBuilder` independently, so if the number is divisible by both 3 and 5, then the contents are `FizzBuzz`.

At last, we'll use a trick with `replaceAll("^$", …)` to conditionally replace the emtpy string by the number.

This actually yields

```
1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz 16 17 Fizz 19 Buzz…
```

Instead of the trick with `replaceAll`, you could also use an `Optional` to simulate an if/else:

```java
System.out.print(Optional.of(sb.toString())
    .filter(t -> !t.isEmpty())
    .orElse(String.valueOf(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String number = Integer.toString(i);
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        sb.append("Fizz");
        number = "";
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        sb.append("Buzz");
        number = "";
    }
    System.out.println(sb.append(number));
}
```

You can also do it without if-statement.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean done = (i % 3 == 0 && sb.append("Fizz") == sb)
                 | (i % 5 == 0 && sb.append("Buzz") == sb)
                 || sb.append(i) == sb;
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Long, String> game = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                3L, "Fizz",
                5L, "Buzz",
                23L, "Custom"));
        System.out.println(fizzBuzz(100, game));
    }

    public static String fizzBuzz(int size, HashMap<Long, String> game) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {

            boolean empty = true;
            for (Long divisor : game.keySet()) {
                if (i % divisor == 0) {
                    output.append(game.get(divisor));
                    empty = false;
                }
            }

            if (empty) {
                output.append(i);
            }
            output.append("\n");
        }

        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] params = {"Fizz\n3","Buzz\n5"};
        
        for (int i = 1; i ++< 100;) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            for (String param: params) {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(param);
                String str = reader.nextLine();
                int x = reader.nextInt();
                reader.close();
                if (i % x == 0) {
                    buffer.append(str);
                }
            }
            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                buffer.append(i);
            }
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        }
    }

}
```